# ThisWorkbook.Protect in Workbook_open() not working 100% of the time

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I have a `ThisWorkbook.Protect` function set at `Workbook_open()` event to make sure i don't leave it unprotected after working with it but it seems to me it doesnt work at all times.

I have made a line that displays MSGBOX "Witamy" inside the code which was my idea of checking if it's working.

Funny thing is that i get a msgbox but i still sometimes can delete sheets which i don't want my coworksers to be able to do.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Call SetPass 'sets iPass variable

ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:=iPass

For Each sh In Worksheets
sh.Protect Password:=iPass, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Next sh

Sheets("Strona główna").Activate

MsgBox "Witamy"
End Sub
```

Note: Loop also works 100% of the time or at least i didn't notice it not working.
Note2: Sometimes if it doesn't work and i close and reopen Workbook it works again

Any idea of how to fix the issue or diffrent approach of preventing leaving workbook unprotected?

Comment: Use the `Workbook_Close` event?

Comment: @user10186832 It doesn't work at all :/ or maybe im doing something wrong 
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Call SetPass
ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:=iPass
End Sub